# Why does Aurelia install so many dependencies?

Tags: aurelia

I am curious to know why when I create a new Aurelia project, each project installs +600 node_modules. Understandably, the modules collectively don't take up a lot of space, but are all of these modules necessary? I was under the impression that Aurelia's aim was to help developers move away from depending on 3rd party libraries so it seems odd that each project comes with a massive dump of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: 90% of these node_modules are building tools. Although they are not necessary they are there to make your life easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are starting your project from CLI - which comes preset with HTTP server, ES6/2015, SASS, live-reloading and more.

I created clean Aurelia project and looked at the package.json - there were 5 dependencies and 34 dev dependencies. Using all of above mentioned tools is somewhat standard in today's JS web development, and generating project from CLI reduces time needed for upfront setup. All of these features come with their own dependencies, and that's why `node_modules/` folder grows rapidly.

The bottom line is - you could start new Aureila project with much fewer dependencies. On their home page you can find [starter project](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1) with just three. But that also means that you won't have access to most of the tools used today.

Also, and correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't got the impression Aurelia ever aimed to move devs from third party libs and modules, just to be modern, fast, and unobtrusive.

Comment: Yep, definitely using CLI. My confusion with my 3rd party statement comes from listening to Rob Eisenberg on Hansel Minutes and reading his post [here](http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/introducing-aurelia/). I am new to Aurelia, so my initial reaction was he was referring to 3rd party libraries, but now I believe that he meant the core Aurelia framework does not have 3rd party dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

All modern web frameworks have a host of tooling.  The reasons in no particular order -

**1. Transpiling ESNext or TypeScript** - if you want to write in Future JavaScript but have it work in all browsers, you need this step.  Both Babel and TypeScript tooling comes with extra stuff too.  If you want to see coverage (everyone does) there's another tool.

**2. Testing** - Unit test and End to End testing require testing frameworks, test runners, and if you want to write like above (esnext or TypeScript) you also need transpiling.

**3. Module Loading / Bundling** - Require.js, JSPM/System.js, WebPack, etc... are used to allow your code to actually *run* in the browser.  Without a module loader you could not break your code out in to separate files.  Without a bundler you would be loading a lot of extra files in production.

**4. Serving your application** - If you want to run your app locally you need a way to serve it up and watch for changes.

**5. Debugging** - You want to debug?  Now you need a way to debug the file that gets served to the browser back to the original source.

**6. Linting** - Lint your code base for style consistencies.

Each of these packages usually have their own dependencies, and they get pulled down as well.

This convention of small packages that have a single focus is arguably better than massive packages that do everything for you.  This allows you to remove a package and replace it with the one that does the same thing but in a way you want it.